# How to open Whatsapp or other iOS app on click of Button in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open an iOS app_B from app_A and then wants the data of app_B back into app_A, tried below to open whatsapp, but didn't work. Please help how to achieve this in iOS, thanks in advance.

```
    @IBAction func clickMe(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?00919599****** "
        let whatUpUrl = NSURL(string: url)
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatUpUrl! as URL){
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatUpUrl! as URL)
        } else {
            //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Whatsapp installed
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "http://whatsapp.com/")! as URL)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**WebUrl Link open Chat**

```
let whatsappURL = URL(string: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9512347895&text=Invitation")
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL!) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL!)
    }
```

Note: Add url scheme in info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Info.plist

[image]

Then on the button you want to open whatsapp use this.

```
 @IBAction func whatsappButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        var str = "Hello to whatsapp"
        str = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: (NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed))!
        let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(str)")

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL! as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL! as URL)
        } else {
            showAlert(message: "Whatsapp is not installed on this device. Please install Whatsapp and try again.")
        }
}
```

Similarly for other apps : 
Replace - 
     NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=(str)") with
     NSURL(string: "APPNAME://").
You will also need to add that app to Info.plist as described above.

Thanks!!

Comment: @Sudhir & Ankit, thanks, guys, what's up is getting opened but I also need the call back into my first app from the second one, can you pls suggest

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @ Ankit : I want a callBack response data of App_B to app_A not necessary it's wats up. e.g. when I open app_B from app_A, app_B perform some tasks and then gives the response back to app_A.